# Theano function theano.tensor.shape_padaxis not found in module

Tags: python, theano

I'm trying to use theano.tensor.shape_padaxis as shown [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.shape_padaxis).
I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'shape_padaxis'

I'm using python 2.7 and theano 0.7
Everything else seems to work correctly.

```
$ python
>>> import theano
>>> theano.version.version
'0.7.0'
>>> tensor = theano.tensor.tensor3()
>>> theano.tensor.shape_padright(tensor)
DimShuffle{0,1,2,x}.0
>>> theano.tensor.shape_padaxis(tensor,axis=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'shape_padaxis'
```

Can anybody reproduce? Any idea where that comes from?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer in the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/Twq4T5V-qE4) for theano users.